# Why are my launcher and panel all glitchy when I open dash since updating my nVidia drivers?

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, launcher, unity-dash

[image]

As you can see in the image, launcher and my panel look a bit glitchy when I open dash. I have used unity-tweak-tool to set the transparency to static blur on dash, and this always worked in the past. I'm not sure what graphics drivers I was before, it was just whatever was installed by default after installing Ubuntu. Since updating to the Nvidia binary proprietary drivers (v331.38) every else has worked fine except things getting a bit glitchy when I open dash.

Does anyone recognize this kind of glitch?

Graphics card info:

> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
>
> Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 710M
>
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
>
> Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
>
> Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>
> Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
>
> I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
>
> [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
>
> Capabilities:
>
> Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: You need to provide more info about your hardware. What graphics card?

Comment: I've edited the question to include graphics card info now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but for what it's worth, you're not alone. I'm running an older Nvidia 9600 GT and I noticed the same thing.